# Spring beans not created as a singleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

This is an old project using Spring 3, with XML-based beans definitions, and I am new to the company/project.

I am just looking for pointers, not necessarily expecting you to find the root problem for me.

Basically, Spring is creating multiple instances of the same class/bean. From the Spring definition of `scope=singleton`, it says that they mean a singleton *per IoC container*, not a singleton in the classic GoF definition https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC1/reference/html/ch03s05.html

As a workaround, my colleague would explicitly add an init-method to each bean definition (that really needed to be a singleton, such as a class containing a cache)

```
 <bean id="myServiceBean" class="com.supercompany.MyCache" init-method="init"/>
```

And in the `init` method, a singleton pattern is implemented, so effectively the same instance is re-used.

There's only one `contextConfiguration` binded to `applicationContext.xml`, and I tried looking searching for the project "classLoader" and "ApplicationContext" hoping to find multiple implementations, but to no avail.

```
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Any other pointers where to look around?

Edit :

My example of MyCache was a bit misleading. After some more investigation, "normal" classes are correctly being instancied as singletons. It's my Service class that is not being created correctly. I am using `javax.ws.rs` annotation

```
@Path("/share")
public class ShareService {
...
}
```

Edit 2: After some more investigation, it's a `Javax-ws-rs`/`JAX-RS` "issue" where by design it is a new instance per request. However, even adding javax-ws-rs's `Singleton` still doesn't work.

Comment: Singleton works as expected in Spring 3 (2012?). You could have multiple Spring contexts e.g. parent an child context or someone overriding the `myServiceBean` bean definition with another definition which uses `prototype` scope. Place a breakpoint in the `MyCache` constructor and start debugging.

Comment: Mayne you are using `cglib` library to handle proxy creation? In older Spring `cglib` was calling the constructor twice due to library limitation.

Comment: Is there any possibility that there are many application contexts? Singleton bean in spring means that there is one instance of bean per application context, not per whole process... The practice to use init method and implement singleton manually sounds really wrong, its kind of using spring on purpose in a wrong way....

Comment: @KarolDowbecki : According to the doc I linked, that's what I am expecting. I will look for cglib, but  I doubt it's that

Comment: @MarkBramnik : That's what I thought, but I didn't find anything. I tried to explain that in the end of my post. Maybe I am not searching correctly. What keyword/classes should I search?

Comment: The best advise here is to not to be afraid of Spring complexity, it's all open source. Just download the sources and see what calls `MyCache` constructor. The details will be in the thread stack e.g. just navigate down until you find the bean names and factories.

Comment: Your comment about "per IoC container, not a singleton in the classic GoF" implies that you have multiple Spring contexts created.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I agree with you, that's my hunch too. The code and definitions look fine, hence my post here looking for pointers. I will try your idea of looking at the stack. Let's hope I can find something useful there!